# Flutter listview not updating after data update

Tags: android-studio, listview, flutter, dart

I have a ListView inside a bottomSheet, that is built using an array of elements. Currently I have one item in there "empty" which is then `.clear()`ed and populated after an async DB call.

The variable update is correct, and I try to use `setState((){})` but the ListView isn't updated at all. I need to close the bottomSheet, reopen it, and the ListView then has the correct items.

Do I need to just call `setState` or does the bottomSheet builder need to be flagged to update?

**Main ListView section:**

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My Map'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
        ),

        //Put in a stack widget so can layer other widgets on top of map widget
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
              mapType: _currentMapType,
              markers: _markers,
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: _center,
                zoom: 11.0,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(width: 16.0),

                    Builder(
                      builder: (context) => FloatingActionButton(   
                          ...
                      ),

                    ),

                    SizedBox(width: 16.0),

                    FloatingActionButton(
                      ...
                    ),

                    SizedBox(width: 16.0),

                    Builder(
                      builder: (context) => FloatingActionButton(
                          child: Icon(Icons.file_download, size: 36.0),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                          onPressed: () {
                            showBottomSheet(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (context) {
                                  return ListView(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                    children: <Widget>[

                                         ...

                                      Divider(),

                                      ListTile(
                                        title: Text("Remote JSON Download"),
                                        trailing:
                                        Icon(Icons.refresh),
                                        selected: true,
                                        onTap: _OnPressedReloadJSON,               <-------------
                                      ),

                                      Divider(),

                                      Container(
                                        height: 150.0,
                                        child: ListView.builder(               <-------------
                                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,

                                          itemCount : testList.length, 
                                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                              return Container(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                                width: 150.0,
                                                color: Colors.red,
                                                child: Text(testList[index]),
                                              );
                                          },

                                        ),
                                      ),
```

**Async Get:**

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  ...

  _OnPressedReloadJSON() {
    fetchJSONAndMakeListTile();
  }

  ...

  List<String> testList= ["empty"];

  Future<http.Response> fetchJSONAndMakeListTile() async {
    final response = await http.get('https://..... file.json');

    // If the server did return a 200 OK response, then parse the JSON.
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List<db_manager.MyObject> myObjects = (json.decode(response.body) as List)
          .map((e) => db_manager.MyObject.fromJson(e))
          .toList();

      testList.clear();
      myObjects.forEach((db_manager.MyObject al) {
        testList.add(al.code);
        print("debug:"+al.code+" - "+al.name);        <------------- prints correctly
      });

      //TODO Does this even work?
      //Trigger update of state - ie redraw/reload UI elements
      setState(() {});

    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response, then throw an exception.
      print(response);
      throw Exception('Failed to load json');
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

I've abstracted the BottomSheet builder into another class (as per another answer) as its own StatefulWidget but I can't seem to access the `void onPress()` method from my main dart file. If the BottomSheet creation/builder is in this separate dart file, how do I call it to build and then update its state with the `async` call updating the listview contents List?

**BottomSheetWidget.dart**

```
class BottomSheetDatabases extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomSheetDatabases createState() => _BottomSheetDatabases();
}

class _BottomSheetDatabases extends State<BottomSheetDatabases> {

  void _onpress() {

  }

  void loadMe() {

  }

  List<String> testList= ["empty"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomSheet(

        builder: (context) {
          return ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                ...

              ),

              Divider(),

              Container(
                height: 150.0,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,

                  itemCount: testList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      key: UniqueKey(),
                      //TODO  ??
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      width: 150.0,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Text(testList[index]),
                    );
                  },

                ),
                //),
                //),
              ),

              ...
```

**Main.dart**:

```
  void _loadSheetDatabases() {
    BottomSheetWidget bottomSheetwidget = BottomSheetWidget();
    bottomSheetwidget.loadMe();
  }
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Seems to me that a `Key` are missing into widget that ListView.Builder returns, try to put a `UniqueKey()` or ValueKey into Container or Text:

```
Container(
   key: UniqueKey(),
   padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
   margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
   width: 150.0,
   color: Colors.red,
   child: Text(testList[index]),
);
```

Comment: Thanks it actually worked for me. The UniqueKey made it work. The only difference is I have not used setState but instead pushing data to stream

Comment: Worked for me. Without it setState did nothing.

Comment: setState sometimes doesn't work with inheritedWidget. Adding UniqueKey() made the trick. Thank you ;)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works like a charm.

Comment: This answer is a life savior

Comment: It works but when you click  on  list item and go to some other screen  and came back to list screen  scroll position is getting changed .

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListView` is only built when `onPressed` is called on your `FloatingActionButton`.
I assume that's why it doesn't get built again when the state changes.

You could wrap the code to build the `ListView` in a new `StatefulWidget` with its own state and then update it when `testList` changes.

Comment: So, so a second `dart` file, which `extends StatefulWidget`, then CreateState, new class extends State<>, which then has `Widget build(BC ctx) { return BottomSheet( builder: .... ` ?

Comment: Yeah, that should work! You can add a method called `updateList(List<String> list)` and hold a reference to the widget to update it

Comment: Hmm, can't seem to get it to work. I've updated the question